# How to convert json file to jmx file (jmeter) using java code?

Tags: java, json, jmeter, jmx

Tried to convert json to xml and from xml to jmx file but couldn't able to convert to jmx file. Someone please help on this to do conversion using plain java code.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Show your code and specify the error / problem you are seeing when trying to convert.

Comment: I have json file which is exported from Postman collections and converted that json file into jmeter jmx file using Loadium tool which is a manual task. Now i am trying to automate the same task using java code with json and jmeter dependencies but i dont know how to do make it done.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Jackson library](https://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2018/apr/10/json-xml-jackson/) in order to convert JSON to XML

   ```
   String jsonString = "" 
           + "{\n \"_links\": {\n" 
           + "    \"individual\": {\n" 
           + "      \"href\": \"/individuals/matching\",\n" 
           + "      \"name\": \"GET\",\n" 
           + "      \"title\": \"Individual Details\"\n" 
           + "    },\n" 
           + "    \"self\": {\n" 
           + "      \"href\": \"/individuals/matching/\"\n" 
           + "    }\n" //
           + "  }\n" //
           + "}";

   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
   JsonNode tree = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
   String jsonAsXml = xmlMapper.writer().withRootName("RootTagName").writeValueAsString(tree);
   ```
2. You can use [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) to build a JMeter Test Plan from Java code, check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for detailed explanation and example code.

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
   import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
   import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
   import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
   import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
   import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
   import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
   import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
   import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

   import java.io.FileOutputStream;

   public class JMeterFromScratch {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           String jmeterHome = "/path/to/your/jmeter/installation";
           StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

           //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
           JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
           JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
           JMeterUtils.initLocale();

           // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
           HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

           // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree

           // HTTP Sampler - open example.com
           HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
           examplecomSampler.setDomain("example.com.com");
           examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
           examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
           examplecomSampler.setMethod("POST");
           examplecomSampler.setName("Open example.com");
           Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
           arguments.addArgument("", jsonAsXml, "");
           examplecomSampler.setArguments(arguments);
           examplecomSampler.addNonEncodedArgument("", jsonAsXml, "");
           examplecomSampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
           examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
           examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


           // Loop Controller
           LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
           loopController.setLoops(1);
           loopController.setFirst(true);
           loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
           loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
           loopController.initialize();

           // Thread Group
           ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
           threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
           threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
           threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
           threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
           threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
           threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

           // Test Plan
           TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
           testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
           testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
           testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

           // HTTP Request Sampler and JSR223 PostProcessor
           HashTree httpRequestTree = new HashTree();
           httpRequestTree.add(examplecomSampler);

           // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
           testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
           HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
           threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);

           SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/test.jmx"));

           //Add Summarizer output
           Summariser summer = null;
           String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
           if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
               summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
           }

           // Store Execution Results into a .csv file
           String csvFile = jmeterHome + "/bin/result.csv";
           ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
           logger.setFilename(csvFile);
           testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

           //Run Test Plan
           jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
           jmeter.run();

           System.exit(0);

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I can able to convert json to xml file using java but i dont know how to convert xml to jmx file using java. Pls help on this.

Comment: The above code demonstrates how you can add generated XML as a HTTP Request sampler body payload, if your requirement is different - you need to be more specific as we are not telepathic enough to guess what you mean

Comment: I have json file which is exported from Postman collections and converted that json file into jmeter jmx file using Loadium tool which is a manual task. Now i am trying to automate the same task using java code with json and jmeter dependencies but i dont know how to do make it done.